# How to change the color of calltips in Anjuta?

Tags: c++, linux, ide, gnome, anjuta

I use fedora 22, and `dnf install -y anjuta`.

I create a new C++ project and write the following code:

```
int hello(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    hello(
    // After I have typed '(', the calltips window popped up,
    // but the background color and text are too dark to tell.
    // The calltips window cannot be captured through screenshot.

    return 0;
}

int hello(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

How to change the color of calltips in Anjuta?

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ questions. THese are two different languages. Note that settings may be language-specific for a tool. If not, do not add any language tag at all (which is assume here).

Answer (score 0):

`Anjuta` uses a plugin to implement the editor. Actually, the preferred plugin is a `gtk` module called `GtkSourceView`, but you could have chosen `Scintilla` when you started your project. Though some aspects of GtkSourceView can be edited from inside Anjuta, other aspects are managed 'system-wide' (you can find the configuration files probably in `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0` (or `-2.0`).

On a vanilla (= unmodified) system, the calltips will probably be ok, but if you use an alternative system theme (particularly 'dark' themes, like I do), then all bets are off. Some themes change color details in harmony. Others only change some aspects which can then clash with changes you made in the Anjuta/gtksourceview settings (setting for themes are in `/usr/share/themes/<your theme>/<your gtk>`.

Theming in `gtk3` is in a state of continuous change at the moment. Latest `gtk3.20.x` changed things once again. So, if you're audacious, have a look around in the above files. It's quite an adventure. The simplest solution is to try some of the alternative 'Color schemes', (in `Edit|Preferences|GtkSourceView Editor|Font`), the definition of each of which is in the `usr/share/gtksourceview` directory mentioned above.

This problem is not unique to `Anjuta`, most, if not all, other IDEs suffer from very similar issues.